# How can we recommend new question close flags? For example: "can't answer because didn't provide code" on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, custom-close-reasons

I've been contributing a bit lately to Stack Overflow and I have noticed an extremely common trend for new users to post questions explaining their problem, but not providing any code.
Things like:

> I have an api built in flask but it's not updating the SQL database, can you help?.

It's a useless question and worth closing. If it had code we could reasonably pinpoint a problem, and make good record for the future. But the closest close question flag is "this lacks clarity". I feel like having a close question flag specifically dedicated to lack of code would help new users to realise why their questions are being closed.

Comment: Ask that question at Meta Stack Overflow please.

Comment: While there is more than one site where inclusion of a minimal reproducible example is helpful, so your question *is* applicable to multiple sites and on-topic here, each site is a tiny bit different in what is expected; though asking ***here*** for a new close reason is fair. Stack Overflow has, for example, [this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283185/3648282) where you'll gain a following from many people directly affected.

Comment: The answer to your actual question in the title is probably "here on meta" though as of late, posting on meta has not seemed to actually be a good way to reach those who make decisions about these things. It vaguely seems to be improving again, but this definitely needs to go with a "don't hold your breath" caveat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't need a new reason for that; we already have *two* that apply. The off-topic reason:

> **It's seeking debugging help but needs more information.** The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

and the one you already mentioned:

> **Needs details or clarity**
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

The linked Help Center page warns against questions lacking code, e.g. under "Help others reproduce the problem".